# Disable colors in cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql

cqlsh, the CQL command prompt for Apache Cassandra, is programmed to show colors in the query results. Is there an easy way to disable colors in cqlsh ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have `$TERM` set to something that doesn't support color. For example,

```
~$ TERM=dumb cqlsh
```

Answer (score 9):

To disable color output use ./bin/cqlsh --no-color

Refer

Comment: This answer is the actual answer that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It appears that although there is a `--color` option, it does not provide a way to disable colors, so I've opened [CASSANDRA-4634](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4634) to fix that.

As a side note, if the `--file` option is used, colors will be disabled, in case that's what you're worried about.