# Powershell character encoding

Tags: powershell, cassandra

I'm using powershell to run the cassandra shell. The cassandra host is a linux box. When running a query, I get this:

```
cqlsh> use mykeyspace;
cqlsh:mykeyspace> select * from person;

 ←[0;1;35mid←[0m | ←[0;1;35mphone←[0m
----+-------------------------------
  ←[0;1;32m1←[0m | ←[0;1;34m{←[0m←[0;1;33malias←[0m←[0;1;34m: ←[0m←[0;1;33m'asd'←[0m←[0;1;34m, ←[0m←[0;1;33mnumber←[0m←[0;1;34m: ←[0m←[0;1;33m'asd'←[0m←[0;1;34m}←[0m

(1 rows)
```

If I run the same thing through cmd, the output is fine. It's only when run through powershell do these weird characters appear. I'm guessing this is an encoding issue. Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Disable colors in cqlsh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326648/disable-colors-in-cqlsh). The additional characters are escape sequences for coloring output in Linux/Unix terminals.

Comment: Yup...that was it. cqlsh --no-color resolves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find a way to mark this as answered without adding an answer. Following Ansgar's link, starting cqlsh with:

```
cqlsh hostip --no-color
```

resolves the issue.